# List with events in Rome

Tags: online-resources, events, rome

In June I'm going to visit Rome. Is there a (good) website where I can find events, concerts, etc. that take place in Rome?

Comment: A simple google search for the keywords 'rome events 2012' gives you plenty results for you :)

Comment: Yes, I know Google :-) I want to know if anybody knows a dedicated event page that is good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for concerts, festivals and things like that, this list can be useful:

http://eventful.com/rome/events

Another event list that is very useful is [In Rome Now](http://www.inromenow.com/site%20templates/index.htm). It is a little bit at short hand notice, but it always lists the events for the coming week.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you can find a lot of results using Google, but if you are looking for something more customized, have a look to [Guiomatic](http://www.guiomatic.com/en). That's an automatic guide generator based on the city you want to visit and the dates you will be there.