# Easy way to find out what's happening in Centri Sociali and other counter-cultural spaces in Rome?

Tags: online-resources, italy, culture, rome, events

Is there a website or similar that gathers all the (public) activities in [Centri Sociali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-managed_social_centers_in_Italy) and other leftist counter-cultural venues, to make it easier for an outsider to find out what's happening on a given day?

Examples for other cities might be [demosphere](https://demosphere.eu/) (Many cities in France) or [Kalinka](http://www.kalinka-m.org/) (Munich), my interest is more in concerts and parties than rallies and talks.

I only skimmed the resources given in the answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6945/list-with-events-in-rome), but it does not seem to cover the self-organized spaces I'm interested in.

Answer (score 3):

There is [a website listing a few CSOA's in Rome](http://www.cosafarearoma.it/centri-sociali-roma/). In addition, google is your friend. Search for "CSOA Roma" and check out the results. (CSOA stands for Centro Sociale Occupato Autogestito.) These are a good start. From there onwards, your best bet is to check if the centre has a facebook page. An alternative is to visit the centre itself and to look for posters / flyers advertising events. Due to the semi-illegal and underground nature of the CSOA's events tend not to be advertised on a mass scale. You are likely to find posters in and close to the centre but not all around the city.